# Database cluster... without Master/Slave?

Tags: mysql, database, replication, mysql-replication

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a set of **SQLdb servers** to which data is written and have them **replicate**, avoiding conflicting information.

I imagine that a **Master/Slave** structure would be mandatory, I would like to know if a system where servers have no hierarchy could support replication.

Currently I'm using **MySQL**, but I would be happy to move to another database if needed.

---

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/130961/what-database-is-easy-to-maintain-and-manage-in-a-cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a multi-master setup / cluster.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-master_replication

Postgresql has similar features to Mysql but it considered more enterprise class, yet is also OSS.  It is easy to get excellent support for it via #postgresql on irc.freenode.net

I'm not sure if there would be some affects on ACID though.

Comment: What would you say makes Postgres more "enterprise class"?

Comment: Postgres has been historically more of an enterprise class database because:

Better adherence to SQL

Superior ACID compliance.

A richer feature set

It did not install a risky storage engine by default (MyIsam)

Full support for foreign keys

Full transactions support


Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems
 & 
http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/ for more details

Answer (score 1):

Multi master setup is the only one setup whith no hierarchy to comes to my mind right know. By the way, there's the DRDB option for replicating data that might fit your needs using [DRDB](http://www.drbd.org/) and [Heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat) for failover.